# How to create & train a neural model to use for Core ML

Tags: neural-network, coreml

Apple introduced Core ML. There are many third parties providing trained models.

But what if I want to create a model myself? How can I do that and what tools & technologies can I use?

Answer (score 31):

Core ML doesn't provide a way to train your own models. You only can convert existing ones to Apple 'mlmodel' format.

To create your own neural networks, use [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) or [Keras](https://keras.io/) frameworks and then convert those models to CoreML format. For traditional machine learning algorithms Core ML is also compatible with [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/)* and [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You can also train and run neural networks on iOS without Core ML, just use [Caffe 2](https://caffe2.ai/) or [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). I support a [long list of iOS-compatible machine learning libraries](http://alexsosn.github.io/ml/2015/11/05/iOS-ML.html), if you're interested.

All libraries mentioned above have a great documentation and a lot of tutorials for you to start creating your own models.

---

*LibSVM is also compatible, but scikit-learn uses it under the hood anyway.