# How to train an ML model?

Tags: machine-learning, training-data, ios11, coreml, coremltools

As you may now, `Apple` introduced `Core ML` for `iOS 11` in this year's `WWDC`. This framework makes use of an already trained ML model in an specific format that you can convert if your source model doesn't match it. `Apple` also makes available for downloading and directly integratiing some already trained ML models [here](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/).

On the other hand, they also mentioned at the `WWDC 2017` that you can train model by using tools such as `Caffe` or `Keras`.

I'd like to train a model with a more specific purpose than the ones already trained and provided by `Apple`, that look quite generic ones. But I'm not an ML expert and I'd appreciate an starting point for this.

Where can I find models that I can train? And then, how can I train them? I'm looking for some posts or tutorials for this with no success. I read some posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627276/how-to-create-train-a-neural-model-to-use-for-core-ml), but it doesn't provide the guidelines I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find pretrained (CNN) Keras models documented here: https://keras.io/applications/

The Keras blog is a good starting point too: https://blog.keras.io/category/tutorials.html

And these are very good tutorials: http://machinelearningmastery.com/start-here/